# Repeating digits in difference of squares of 8-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Came across a question like this today and I couldn't figure out where to start.

There are some unique 8-digit number pairs (call them $m$ and $n$) that the difference of their squares (that is, $m^2-n^2$) results in a set of repeating digits. What are the possibilities of digits that can be repeated?

Also – not sure what the right tag for this would be; apologies if I got it wrong.

Comment: "*results in a set of repeating digits*"... to be clear, you mean to say that $m^2-n^2$ for such a pair would be a number like $555$ or $7777777$ or something else like that, where it is some amount, greater than one digit in length where all digits are the same?  And then, you are asking what... only which digits are possible but length of the number is irrelevant?  or are you further asking what numbers at all are possible where length of the number is included?

Comment: Yes, a number like 5555, etc. Apparently not all numbers 1-9 can show up repeating from $m^2 - n^2$. I'm wondering which digits 1-9 are possible to show up repeating from the difference of two different 8-digit numbers.

Comment: Well, looking at it modulo10 doesn't tell us much.  Noting that $m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)$ the result will either be zero or will be at least eight digits long, so we can look at the result modulo, lets say $16$.  We know that $m^2-n^2$ can never be $2,6,10,14$ mod 16 and a number mod16 is equivalent to its final three digits mod16, that it could never end in $222$ or in $666$.  What remains to show is that all others are possible or find additional arguments as to why they are not.  At this point, I'd start building examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the digits modulo $4$, we know that since the only possible squares modulo $4$ are $0$ or $1$, the only possible differences would be $0,1,$ or $3$ mod4.  In particular, $m^2-n^2$ is *never* $2$mod4.  This implies that since any number modulo 4 is equivalent to the final two digits modulo 4, if the final two digits are the same they cannot be $22$ or $66$ as these are $2$mod4.

From here, it remains to show that each of the others are possible.  Indeed:

$$18518520^2-18518517^2=111111111$$

Ending in twos is not possible

$$18518523^2-18518514^2=333333333$$

$$11111112^2-11111110^2=44444444$$

$$18518526^2-18518511^2=555555555$$

Ending in sixes is not possible

$$18518529^2-18518508^2=777777777$$

$$11111113^2-11111109^2=88888888$$

$$18518532^2-18518505^2=999999999$$

$$m^2-m^2=0$$

These numbers were constructed by looking at the prime factorization of $111111111=3^2\cdot37\cdot 333667=3\cdot 37037037$ and recognizing that we could express $37037037$ as the sum of two numbers very close to it's half.